# Continuous Haar Wavelet for Python

Tags: python, haar-wavelet, wavelet-transform

I am looking for an implementation of Continuous Wavelet Transform for Python that includes Haar Wavelet.

I would like to reproduce the experiment given by MathWorks for Matlab, at [this link](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/gs/continuous-wavelet-transform.html).

I tried with Pyscellania but I obtain completely different coefficients.

Is there a Python implementation of the CWT out there that includes the Haar Wavalet apart from Pyscellania?

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: It's a request for a link to a good Python implementation of CWT that includes Haar Wavelet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It looks pretty clear to me, I told you what I am looking for, it's obvious that my question is how to get it

Comment: Try the Mahotas library http://mahotas.readthedocs.io/en/latest, or PyWavelets http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is clear.

Have you tried Pyscellania's normalised or standard Haar Wavelet?

Maybe you are just using the wrong one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Actually I have tried both. Mathworks does not precise which one is using but no one of Pyscellania's transforms give the results obtained with Matlab.