# how to change dilation and translation coefficient in pywt

Tags: python, wavelet, haar-wavelet, pywavelets, pywt

I am new to pywt and wavelet analysis.
I am now facing several problems, and I hope someone can help me with them.

[image]

First, I would like to change dilation (D) and translation (x) in my_wavelet, but I do not know how to do it exactly. I will be very grateful if anyone provides an example(s).

Second, can I add zeros at the edge of array s? Since the output of value cA and cD are in size 7 while input s is size 13. Or is there any method to avoid the reduction of size?

Third, is C_P,D in the formula above the same as cA output from pywt.dwt function? I still don't understand why in the formula there's only one output but pywt.dwt gave two?

```
s = [1,2,3,7,8,9,5,1,1,0,1]
my_filter_bank = ( [1,1], [-1,1], [1,1], [-1,1] )
my_wavelet = pywt.Wavelet('haar', filter_bank = my_filter_bank)
cA, cD = pywt.dwt(s, my_wavelet)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you get mixed-up between the *Continuous* Wavelet Transform and the *Discrete* Wavelet Transform. The formula that you provide is that of the CWT, yet what you try computing in Python is the DWT.

> **First**, I would like to change dilation (D) and translation (x) in my_wavelet, but I do not know how to do it exactly. I will be very grateful if anyone provides an example(s).

You don't have to, at least not if you're planning on applying a DWT to your signal s. DWT will decompose your signal using a single level (using `dwt`) or multiple levels (using `wavedec`). Think of each level as being related to the scale of the wavelet, *i.e.* how dilated it is. So the dilation and the translation of your wavelet are already "taken care of".

> **Second**, can I add zeros at the edge of array s? Since the output of
> value cA and cD are in size 7 while input s is size 13. Or is there
> any method to avoid the reduction of size?

The size of cA and cD is defined [here](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/dwt-discrete-wavelet-transform.html):

> Length of coefficients arrays depends on the selected mode. For all
> modes except periodization:
>
> ```
> len(cA) == len(cD) == floor((len(data) + wavelet.dec_len - 1) / 2)
> ```
>
> For periodization mode (“per”):
>
> ```
> len(cA) == len(cD) == ceil(len(data) / 2)
> ```

The fact that cA and cD have a different size than your input signal s should not bother you. Of course, you can add zeros at the edge of your signal, but this would only result in you computing the coefficients from the zero-padded signal.

> **Third**, is C_P,D in the formula above the same as cA output from
> pywt.dwt function? I still don't understand why in the formula there's
> only one output but pywt.dwt gave two?

No, they are not the same thing. C_P,D in your formula is the wavelet coefficient for a given scale and position, whereas cA and cD correspond to the detailed and approximate coefficients.

One last tip: I personally find it very hard to get an understanding of the wavelet transform with a small array such as yours. I would suggest analyzing example data such as scipy's ecg:

```
import pywt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram

s = electrocardiogram()
plt.plot(s)
plt.title('INPUT SIGNAL')
```

[image]

```
my_wavelet = pywt.Wavelet('db2')
cA, cD = pywt.dwt(s, my_wavelet) 
plt.plot(cD)
plt.title('DETAILED COEFF.')
```

[image]

```
plt.plot(cA)
plt.title('APPROXIMATION COEFF.')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I confirm now I would like to use CWT with haar wavelet. However, pywt does not provide CWT with haar, and scipy does not support self-defined wavelet. Thus, I still do not know how to do CWT with haar wavelet now. Do you have any comments? Thanks again.

Comment: Indeed, in pywt the Haar wavelet is meant to be used with the DWT (you can confirm this by trying `print(my_wavelet)`). I am not sure what alternative to recommend. This SO answer suggests using Pyscellania: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169856/continuous-haar-wavelet-for-python